# correctly load styles and scripts in react gutenberg block plugin

Tags: css, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm creating a gutenberg block that I'm trying to correctly load a stylesheet. It's working in development but as soon as I zip up the file and use the block plugin on the staging site i returns a 404. My custom css file does not exist int he build/ directory.

In my plugin-gallery.php file i'm registering the stylesheet plugin-gallery.css and then enqueuing it with wp_enqueue_style, as stated in the [block reference guide](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/#style) -> "It’s possible to pass a style handle registered with the wp_register_style function or a path to a CSS file relative to the block.json file. I have tried both a direct link to the file and the handle and neither work.

The code i'm using to register the stylesheet:

```
function plugin_gallery_block(){
 wp_register_style( 'plugin-gallery-css', plugins_url( '/src/plugin-gallery.css', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'plugin-gallery-css',
        plugins_url( '/src/plugin-gallery.css', __FILE__ )
    );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'plugin_gallery_block' );
```

An extract from the block.json:

```
 "style": ["file:./style-index.css","plugin-gallery-css"],
```

Any thoughts on what I should look out for or try next?

There's a screenshot of the 404 error in the network tab of the browser.

[image: Network view in inspector]

[image: File structure]

Comment: did you "build" it before deploying? It might be that you are just running `npm run dev` but should run `npm run build` before  zipping and deploying it.
other than that I think you may have to use `plugins_url( 'src/plugin-gallery.css' .....)` without the extra slash infront.

Comment: yes i ran build to no avail. the solution i found was to build the project then manually copy over the files that were not copied over in the build script. maybe if i looked into how the webpack setup works i could work it out but for now this solution works for me temporarily but its not ideal. thanks for your response though.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS file `style-index.css` is being included in the plugin zip as its defined in the block.json and mostly likely included in index.js. The other CSS file, `plugin-gallery.css` is being enqueued via PHP via `plugin_gallery_block()` but it is not included in the build zip as PHP files aren't parsed for file dependancies to include.

In package.json, you can [specify extra files to be included](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#files) with build/zip, try:

```json
{
    "name": "mycustom-block",
     ...
    "files": [
        "src/plugin-gallery.css"
    ]
}
```